# Error while opening Mist on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mist, ubuntu

I want to connect mist on my private net however it give error of already connect but there is no connect there. Please advise me how to resolve the issue.

Note:- Please see the attached error screen shot[image]

Comment: Hi there. Do you already have Geth or another client running? Or do you have something else running on port 30303?

Comment: Yes geth is running on background so i want to connect the private net.